# php change several line in a block of string

Tags: php

I have store my back-end content in my database.
Now i need modify something, and i export all them to a php array, and list out one by one to make some modify on it

The php array was example like this (may watch carefully)

```
$newArray=array(array('first'=>'<p><img src='http://www.abc.com/images/everything/image1.jpg'></p><p><img src='http://www.hermo.my/images/path/image2.jpg'></p>',
'second'=>'<p><img src='http://www.abc.com/images/path23/image3.jpg'></p><p><img src='http://www.hermo.my/images/path25/image4.jpg'></p>'),
array('first'=>'<p><img src='http://www.abc.com/images/everything/image5.jpg'></p><p><img src='http://www.hermo.my/images/path/image6.jpg'></p>',
'second'=>'<p><img src='http://www.abc.com/images/path23/image7.jpg'></p><p><img src='http://www.hermo.my/images/path25/image8.jpg'></p>'));
```

and i call out 1 by 1 by foreach

```
foreach(newArray as $a){
$first=$a['first'];
}
```

All i wanna do is modify all image's path in the content to same url like

```
http://www.cde.com/image/image1.jpg
http://www.cde.com/image/image2.jpg
http://www.cde.com/image/image3.jpg
http://www.cde.com/image/image4.jpg
```

how to do that?
in my array i got thousand more results, some of the image path is same, many are different
thanks

Comment: It sounds like what you are wanting to do is parse the HTML in those strings.  For that, you're going to want to use an HTML parser.  Don't try to do it with regular expressions.   See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Do you want to change the values *in* your database? If so, dump the corresponding table and use a text editor with search/replace to change your paths.

Comment: Andy - i heard thoudsand times of regular expression, but what actually that is?